# Uniting selectors

Tags: html, css

When I unite class and class (or id and id, it doesn't matter), why the changes apply for only one element?

Example: picture and text under picture:

```
.photo
{
    width: 230px; height: 230px;
    margin: 15px;
}

    .photo:hover + .name
    {
        color: black;
    }

.name
{
    text-align: center;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: `+` selector does not concatenate classes in css, to do that simply separate each range of selectors with a comma `.photo:hover, .name`. The **adjacent sibling combinator** (`+`) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it *immediately* follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: Also, what is your HTML? We can't say for sure what you are doing wrong unless we see your layout

Answer (score 0):

```
.photo:hover + .name {
  color: black;
}
```

Example:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: blue;
}

.photo:hover + .name {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">.photo</div>
<div class="name">.name</div>
```

This code means: when elements with class `photo` are hovered, and the next element on the same level has class `name`, the color of element with class `photo` will be changed to black.

If you want to apply the same CSS rules to multiple tags/IDs/classes, you need to use comma, like this:

```
.photo:hover, .name {
  color: black;
}
```

Example:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: blue;
}

.photo:hover, .name {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">.photo</div>
<div class="name">.name</div>
```

In this case, black color will be applied to elements with `name` class, and to hovered elements with `photo` class.

Comment: This wrong, isn't it? Because if I unit selector with "+", it changes class="name".

Comment: @Duddits: Are you looking for an explanation of why it doesn't work with + or are you trying to contest the status quo? Maybe you should clarify what you mean by "unite" because it's a very strange word to use in this context.

Comment: @Duddits, when you use `selector + selector`, it means that if in DOM you have 2 elements `<selector>` at the same level, and `<selector>` goes after `<selector>` (and there are no additional elements between them), the style will be applied to the second `<selector>` element.

Answer (score 0):

the + is not used to select a common style for both the classes. '+' is the symbol for the adjacent sibling selector it selects all elements that are the adjacent siblings of a specified element. if u want to add some common style to both the classes then just seperate both classes with common like .photo:hover , .name {color: black;} or you can use some common words in the class name like instead of photo you can write "photo color" and instead of name "name color" and then style it by using .color{color: black;} in this case black color will be applied to both of your classes or you can use attribute selector with common class name [class*="color"]{color: black;} this will also do the same effect.